# 2 foreign keys in same table, other solution?

Tags: sql

I am trying to create a database that allows me to handle producing items, but i'm not sure this is the best way to do it

> #### Table product
>
> PK: productid

Rest of the producttable isn't very important so it's omitted.

> #### Table product_components
>
> PK: productid & ingredientID
>
> productID (fk)
>
> IngredientID(fk to product)
>
> Quantity

Is this the correct solution or is there a more performant way for me to handle this?

Comment: I assume your `product_components` table is like a many-to-many relationship to the same table? In plain english, could it be described as "For this product, these are its ingredients (which are also products)"?

Comment: this is often called a link-table or an associative-table - it is a good solution

Comment: The primary key should be separate though - either hidden (i.e. no primary key), or an auto-incremental number (e.g. serial in `postgresql`, auto increment in `mysql`, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

A many to many relation is usually resolved the way you present here. Afterwards you can obtain one level of components of a product with a simple join:

```
select prod.*, comp.*, pc.quantity
from product prod 
  join product_components pc on (prod.productid=pc.productid)
  join product comp on (comp.productid= pc.IngredientID)
where prod.productId=?
;
```

This model reduces redundant data and so the performance of this solution in terms of space is good as long as the components are used in more and more products, the products have lots of components and you have many levels: products of products of products …  Also with no redundant data you reduce inconsistencies in the database.

Performance in terms of speed will depend on the data and which queries you will be doing, but this model usually performs well with the correct indexes.